# How to implement paging in inner RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-paging

My architecture is MVVM. For implementing paging I used paging library from architecture component.
I need paging for outer recycler view and inner recycler view. For outer recycler view I successfully implemented it, but for inner recycler view I don’t know how to implement.
I implemented paging like in this article for outer recycler view

https://proandroiddev.com/8-steps-to-implement-paging-library-in-android-d02500f7fffe

**UPDATE**

I implemetened my inner recycler view like this example and it works, but I think it's not preferable solution 
[how to use paging when recyclerview item have another recyclerview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52344563/how-to-use-paging-when-recyclerview-item-have-another-recyclerview)

Answer (score 0):

Just add `ViewPager` inside your `ViewHolder` item view, and do all `ViewPager` logic inside `onBindViewHolder()`

Comment: I don't think this is help me. Because for inner recycler view I implemented data source like this https://gist.github.com/anitaa1990/ef63b4a622831ad740a799fe27c7983c#file-feeddatasource-java. But I don't know how to connect it with inner Recycler View. I had few ideas but it didn't help me

Comment: for outer recycler view I connected it like this in activity
mViewModel.mCardList?.observe(this, Observer {
            adapter.submitList(it)
        })
But  how to do this for inner recycler view

Comment: If you know some examples or article about this please share with me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52344563/how-to-use-paging-when-recyclerview-item-have-another-recyclerview I implemetened my inner recycler view like this example and it works, but I think it's not preferable solution